# How can I list audio devices that playing sound with c#

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

I'am trying to make an app with c# WPF and I need to list audio devices that playing sound. I'am new at c# so can you explain more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

With [`cscore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CSCore/) you can do it

```
using (var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
using (var collection = enumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.All))
// ^^^ take a look on parameters here, you can filter devices with it
{
    foreach (var device in collection)
    {
       //your device using here
       //don't forget to dispose device, because it is MMDevice which inherited from IDiposable
    }
}
```

Then let's imagine you would like to check current playing level

```
 using (var meter = AudioMeterInformation.FromDevice(device))
 {
     if(meter.PeakValue > 0)
     {
         //your code here
     }
 }
```

And if you need to filter output devices by outputting processes take a look on [`AudioSession`](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore.Test/CoreAudioAPI/AudioSessionTests.cs)

```
using (var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
using (var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())
{
    foreach (var session in sessionEnumerator)
    {
            //each session will be assigned to any process
            //implement your logic to select preferred

        using (var meterInformation = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>())
        {
            var peak = meterInformation.PeakValue;
            //here you can check peak value and implement your wishes
        }
    }
}
```

But it is for Win platform only. Author announced [cross platform version](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/tree/netstandard) only as experimental